# RSpec custom diffable matcher

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a custom matcher in RSpec, that ignores whitespaces / newlines, and just matches content:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_matching_content do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual.gsub(/\s/,'').should == expected.gsub(/\s/,'')
  end

  diffable
end
```

I can use it like this:

```
    body = "   some data   \n more data"
    body.should be_matching_content("some data\nmore wrong data")
```

However, when a test fails (like the one above), the diff output looks not good:

```
   -some data
   -more wrong data
   +   some data   
   + more data
```

Is it possible to configure the diffable output? The first line `some data` is right, but the second `more wrong data` is wrong. It would be very useful, to only get the second line as the root cause of the failure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you should disable default `diffable` behaviour in RSpec and substitute your own implementation:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_matching_content do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    @stripped_actual = actual.gsub(/\s/,'')
    @stripped_expected = expected.gsub(/\s/,'')
    expect(@stripped_actual).to eq @stripped_expected
  end

  failure_message do |actual|
    message = "expected that #{@stripped_actual} would match #{@stripped_expected}"
    message += "\nDiff:" + differ.diff_as_string(@stripped_actual, @stripped_expected)
    message
  end

  def differ
    RSpec::Support::Differ.new(
        :object_preparer => lambda { |object| RSpec::Matchers::Composable.surface_descriptions_in(object) },
        :color => RSpec::Matchers.configuration.color?
    )
  end
end

RSpec.describe 'something'do
  it 'should diff correctly' do
    body = "   some data   \n more data"
    expect(body).to be_matching_content("some data\nmore wrong data")
  end
end
```

produces the following:

```
Failures:

  1) something should diff correctly
     Failure/Error: expect(body).to be_matching_content("some data\nmore wrong data")
       expected that somedatamoredata would match somedatamorewrongdata
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -somedatamorewrongdata
       +somedatamoredata
```

You can use custom differ if you want, even reimplement this whole matcher to a system call to `diff` command, something like this:

```
♥ diff -uw --label expected --label actual <(echo "   some data    \n more data") <(echo "some data\nmore wrong data")
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
    some data    
- more data
+more wrong data
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

You can override the `expected` and `actual` methods that will then be used when generating the diff. In this example, we store the expected and actual values as instance variables and define methods that return the instance variables:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_matching_content do |expected_raw|
  match do |actual_raw|
    @actual = actual_raw.gsub(/\s/,'')
    @expected = expected_raw.gsub(/\s/,'') 
    expect(expected).to eq(@actual)
  end

  diffable
  attr_reader :actual, :expected
end
```

Another example is to match for specific attributes in two different types of objects. (The expected object in this case is a `Client` model.)

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_attributes_of_v1_client do |expected_client|
  match do |actual_object|
    @expected = client_attributes(expected_client)
    @actual = actual_object.attributes
    expect(actual_object).to have_attributes(@expected)
  end

  diffable
  attr_reader :actual, :expected

  def failure_message
    "expected attributes of a V1 Client view row, but they do not match"
  end

  def client_attributes(client)
    {
      "id" => client.id,
      "client_type" => client.client_type.name,
      "username" => client.username,
      "active" => client.active?,
    }
  end
end
```

Example failure looks like this:

```
Failure/Error: is_expected.to have_attributes_of_v1_client(client_active_partner)
  expected attributes of a V1 Client view row, but they do not match
  Diff:
  @@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
   "active" => true,
  -"client_type" => #<ClientType id: 2, name: "ContentPartner">,
  +"client_type" => "ContentPartner",
   "id" => 11,
```

Comment: Note this is only mentioned in the rspec docs starting at version 3.4. Also, according to the docs you don't need the `attr_reader` if you use `@actual` as the instance variable name.

Comment: I tried it out and it seems like, you do need them. Without the attr_reader the `@actual` and `@expected` instance variables aren't used (RSpec 3.8)

Comment: This is still working as of Rspec 3.10 and was the best solution for me

Answer (score 1):

There is a gem called [diffy](https://github.com/samg/diffy) which can be used.

But it goes through a string line by line and compares them so instead of removing all whitespace you could replace any amount of whitespace with a newline and diff those entries.

This is an example of something you could do to improve your diffs a little bit. I am not 100% certain about where to insert this into your code.

```
def compare(str1, str2)
  str1 = break_string(str1)
  str2 = break_string(str2)
  return true if str1 == str2
  puts Diffy::Diff.new(str1, str2).to_s
  return false
end

def break_string(str)
  str.gsub(/\s+/,"\n")
end
```

The diffy gem can be set to produce color output suitable for the terminal.

Using this code would work like this

```
str1 = 'extra some                 content'
str2 = 'extra more content'
puts compare(str1, str2)
```

this would print

```
 extra
 -some   # red in terminal
 +more   # green in terminal
 content
 \ No newline at end of file
```